# HTML: How do I remove < between two buttons

Tags: html

Can someone help? I keep getting a < between my two buttons. This is a html page. I have a send and reset button but I keep getting < between both buttons.

```
<form action="mailto:" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        Name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail:<br>
        <input type="text" name="mail"><br>
        Your Message:<br>
        <input type="text" name="Your Message" size="50" style="height:100px"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
<       <input type="reset" value="Reset">
        </form>

This is what I get---->    Submit   <   Reset
```

I don't know how to paste the actual screen shot.

Comment: Just look carefully and you’ll see that you have some text (‘<’ on the same row as reset, just at the beginning of it) between them.

Comment: You should get up from your pc, walk a bit, come back, look at this again.

Comment: `<       <input type="reset" value="Reset">` -> `<input type="reset" value="Reset">`

Comment: Thank you everyone. I had a long day. I see it now. I will definitely get some rest after this. It's working now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the left of your script... You have a "<" randomly placed , HTML might be picking that up